# making gridview rows bold

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to bold all the rows of the gridview on the click event of the button in javascript so for e,g I have this button

```
<asp:button runat="server" text="Test" onclientClick="makerowsBold();"/>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using jQuery, this should work:

CSS:

```
.bold { font-weight:bold; }
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
function makerowsBold() {
    $('#idOfYourGridViewTable tr td').addClass('bold');
}
```

For some unknown reason someone insists on not using jQuery/MooTools/etc.

```
function makerowsBold() {
    var cells = document.getElementById("idOfYourGridViewTable").getElementsByTagName("td");
    for ( var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ )
        cells[i].className += " bold";
}​
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EFAEA/3/).

Comment: I am not using jquery, do you have the solution in javascript.

Comment: It's silly to not be using jQuery - just making more work for yourself, but I will edit my answer.

Comment: yeah, the reason is I am not familar with jquery.

Comment: Updated - as you can see, it makes it much more complex to not use jQuery.